# Umlaut over consonant preceding a vowel

Tags: spelling, umlaut, typography

In the photo below, the word "völliger" is spelled with the umlaut over the v:
[image: box from Leica film]

Is this a typo, a design choice, or is there a linguistic explanation?

Comment: Made in England.

Comment: Nice find. Obviously the (English, apparently) printer didn't have an Ö character in his letter case, so had to combine it from two letters and missed the spot.

Comment: @tofro That makes a lot of sense, I was skeptical that it was just a regular typo since v with an umlaut is not a common symbol, but your explanation makes it seem very plausible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This simply is wrong.

It should be:

> BEI VÖLLIGER DUNKELHEIT ENTWICKELN

There is a letter »V̈«, but it is not part of the German language. (Some [Oceanic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_languages) use this letter, for example [Araki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araki_language))